# What are the missing gaps to prove Goldbach Conjecture?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

When Andrew Wiles proved FLT, all he needed to do was to prove "semi-stable elliptic curve case" of Shimura-Taniyama conjecture. He did not need to start from scratch, he just needed to fill this crucial important "missing gap" ?

Is there a similar conjecture (or "missing gap" or "missing links") for Goldbach Conjecture  ? If this conjecture is proved, then Goldbach Conjecture is proved.

Can anyone point some directions ?

Maybe there are many such conjectures. Is there any recent summary ?